# Como chamar um método que está em outro arquivo java?

Tags: java

Aqui está a primeira classe:

```
public class algoritmo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        opcoes();
    }
public static void opcoes(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        System.out.println("Selecione o Algoritmo de Substituicao Desejado");
        System.out.println("1 - FIFO");
        System.out.println("2 - LRU");
        System.out.println("3 - Segunda Chance");
        System.out.println("4 - Otimo");

        num = input.nextInt();

        switch(num){
            case 1:
                FIFO();
            break;

            case 2:
                LRU();
            break;

            case 3:
                SegundaChance();
            break;

            case 4:
                Otimo();
            break;

        }
```

Esse é um método que está no outro arquivo.

```
public class LRU {
    private int qtdePaginas;
    private int qtdeframes;
    int []paginas;
    int [][]matriz;
    int []falhas;
    int []distancia;

    public LRU(){
        System.out.println("LRU");
    }

    public void setPaginas(int []paginas){
        this.paginas = paginas;
    }

    public void setQtdePaginas(int qtdePaginas){
        this.qtdePaginas = qtdePaginas;
    }

    public void setQtdeframes(int atdeframes){
        this.qtdeframes = qtdeframes;
    }

    public void iniciarFalhas(){
        for(int i=0; i<qtdePaginas; i++){
            falhas[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que instanciar a classe `LRU` para utilizar seus métodos de instância (que não têm `static`).

Além disso, vejo que você vai implementar vários algoritmos de substituição, então definir uma interface lhe será muito útil.

Faça isso:

```
public interface AlgoritmoDeSubstituicao {
    public void setPaginas(int[] paginas);
    public void setQuantidadeDePaginas(int quantidadeDePaginas);
    public void setQuantidadeDeFrames(int quantidadeDeFrames);
    public void iniciarFalhas();
}
```

Sua classe `LRU` revisada:

```
public class LRU implements AlgoritmoDeSubstituicao {
    private int quantidadeDePaginas;
    private int quantidadeDeFrames;
    private int[] paginas;
    private int[][] matriz;
    private int[] falhas;
    private int[] distancia;

    public LRU() {
        System.out.println("LRU");
    }

    @Override
    public void setPaginas(int[] paginas) {
        this.paginas = paginas;
    }

    @Override    
    public void setQuantidadeDePaginas(int quantidadeDePaginas) {
        this.quantidadeDePaginas = quantidadeDePaginas;
    }

    @Override
    public void setQuantidadeDeFrames(int quantidadeDeFrames) {
        this.quantidadeDeFrames = quantidadeDeFrames;
    }

    @Override
    public void iniciarFalhas() {
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeDePaginas; i++) {
            falhas[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Sua classe `Algoritmo`:

```
public class Algoritmo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        opcoes();
    }

    public static void opcoes() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        System.out.println("Selecione o algoritmo de substituicao desejado.");
        System.out.println("1 - FIFO");
        System.out.println("2 - LRU");
        System.out.println("3 - Segunda Chance");
        System.out.println("4 - Otimo");

        num = input.nextInt();

        AlgoritmoDeSubstituicao algoritmo;

        switch (num) {
            case 1:
                algoritmo = new FIFO();
                break;

            case 2:
                algoritmo = new LRU();
                break;

            case 3:
                algoritmo = new SegundaChance();
                break;

            case 4:
                algoritmo = new Otimo();
                break;

            default:
                algoritmo = null;
        }

        if (algoritmo == null) {
            // Faça alguma coisa avisando que o usuário escolheu uma opção inválida.
        }

        // Use a variável algoritmo como quiser daqui para baixo.
    }
}
```

Ah, sou fortemente contra o uso de `switch`es e não recomendo o uso deles praticamente nunca. Poderia lhe propor uma alternativa para eliminá-lo que não fosse apenas um monte de `if`s (no caso, seria com um `Map`). Entretanto, como a sua pergunta está em um nível bem iniciante, vamos ficar por aqui.

Comment: AlgoritmoDeSubstituicao algoritmo;
Porque voce escreveu isto_??? nao entendi T.T

Comment: @Ryu1031 Estou declarando uma variável e dentro do `switch` é atribuído um valor a ela. Essa variável representa o algoritmo escolhido pelo usuário.

Comment: mas aqui esta dando erro ao colocar isso :(

Comment: @Ryu1031 Qual erro?